# Nightwatch js assert element values sorted

Tags: javascript, bdd, nightwatch.js

Trying to test a filter feature on a table that I built and not sure how to do it with nightwatch.

I can run through and view all the element values, but not sure how to compare them to see if they are less than or equal to the next

```
Then(/^I should expect to see the returned results ordered from least to greatest$/, () => {
    return client
            .elements('css selector', 'td[class=someColumn]', (results) => {
                for(let i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++){
                    client.elementIdText(results.value[i].ELEMENT, (result) => {
                        console.log(result.value);
                        return result.value;
                    })
                }
            });
});
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Add one more .elementIDText() and reduce the length of results.value by 1 to checl the list is sorted or not.

```
client.elements('css selector', 'td[class=someColumn]', (results) => {
      for(let i = 0; i < results.value.length-1; i++){
            client.elementIdText(results.value[i].ELEMENT, (result1) => {
                   client.elementIdText(results.value[i+1].ELEMENT, (result2) => {
                     if(result1<=result2){
                       }else {
                        return false;}
                    })
             })
       }

});
```